# Custom requests in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, rest, swagger

I see that Django , in the REST Fremework module provide only CRUD requests made for object of a pre-defined model.

Is there a way to create custom Rest API that is available in REST framework or swagger?

Thank you.

Until now I have a workaround to create a model like "request" or "task" , and manage objects of this model with CRUD requests in Swagger.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [Django REST framework Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#pulling-it-all-together), you can pull it all together `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`...

In REST API commons, we send a request, and we receive a response. Then, if you want to do something with a request, you need to set a "trigger". It might be a GET request when a specific change of data has been done, another python function starts.

from the docs:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def snippet_list(request):
    """
    List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited my response and added a block of code from the documentation, even the link to the section. I that's enough, right? I that does not respond to question, isn't not possible to have a comment from the author?